# Can scientists tell the energy levels of the atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen

In the [hydrogen spectral series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series) how did the scientists know the number of the energy level which the electron is moving from or to?

Answer (score 4):

The numbers are not measured, they are part of a model that explains why the hydrogen atom emits/absorbs only at those wavelengths.

The first series of Hydrogen lines to be discovered was the [Balmer Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series), and nobody knew why they were discrete lines instead of a continuous spectrum. Johann Balmer discovered that the lines all had wavelengths equal to, 
$$\lambda_n = \left({n^2 \over n^2-4}\right)\times 364.5068\;\text{nm.}$$

Later on, it was realized that there were other lines with $m^2$ instead of 4 in the denominator. Later still, the [Bohr model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) of the atom was able to reproduce this pattern of energy levels. Improvements to this came with Quantum Mechanics and various corrections.